# CSS - Font-style propriety - Oblique with variable angle

Tags: html, css, font-style

I would like to choose the angle of inclination of an font with the "font-style: oblique "angle""

Like on this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style

I would also like to use **negative angle**

But I think I missed a detail, when I'm using the exact same snippet in my code the text is always displayed with the default value of inclination (14deg).

Should I use specific font/browser or another css propriety?

Browser : firefox 97.0.1

```css
h2 {
   font-style: oblique 30deg;
}
```

```html
<h2>Oblique text with 30deg angle<h2>
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style#browser_compatibility at least suggests that you should not have any hope of this currently working in any other browser _but_ Firefox.

Comment: It says it right there, that this is a feature of variable fonts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style#variable_fonts The example uses Amstelvar, which is one, https://v-fonts.com/fonts/amstelvar

Answer (score 2):

The reference itself says browser compatibility as given link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style#browser_compatibility

So `oblique <angle>` css is not compatible with any other browser except Firefox. You can use italic style or different font family that has same style.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be for an illogical behaviour.
Even if you specify the degrees the oblique searches for the standard font oblique. It it is not available then it uses italic. Only if both cases are not found is when it generates its own oblique with the specified degrees.
In a nutshell: It will only work if your font doesn't have oblique neither italic.